# Keeping prior values when using listview insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Currently I have a gridview that when I click on select it populates values in a listview.
I handle this in code behind using the selectedindexchanged event. And I even populate a text box in the insertitem template for new entries.

```
protected void GridView9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// this handles the transmittal costs
SqlDataSource29.SelectParameters.Clear();
SqlDataSource29.SelectParameters.Add("tc_t_id", App_id);        
SqlDataSource29.InsertParameters.Clear();
ListView1.Visible = true;
ListView1.DataBind();
((TextBox)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("tc_t_idTextBox")).Text = App_id;
```

However the issue arises when I do an insert. I lose value I put into the listviews insertitem texbox tc_t_idTextBox. Actually I lose the value when I edit and delete also.

There must be a way to hold onto that value between inserts.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                Text="Insert" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                Text="Clear" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tc_dateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_date") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tc_costTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_cost") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tc_typeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_type") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tc_commentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_comment") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tc_t_idTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("tc_t_id") %>' Enabled="false" Width="15"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `DataBind()` on every PostBack, the ListView is being reloaded every time the user performs and action. In the `Page_Load` of your page, do this instead:

```
SqlDataSource29.SelectParameters.Clear();
SqlDataSource29.SelectParameters.Add("tc_t_id", App_id);        
SqlDataSource29.InsertParameters.Clear();
ListView1.Visible = true;
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
((TextBox)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("tc_t_idTextBox")).Text = App_id;
```

Comment: Sorry. It's not in the page load. it's in the selected index changed of a gridview.

    protected void GridView9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



And when the insert happens the values in the listview get added. But I'm trying to keep the previous inserted values in place and not set to blank.

Comment: That should be fine, since right now the code is rebinding the data on postback, which should not happen. I believe that this code put into the event should work, since when the GridView9 posts back, the ListView will not rebind.

Comment: Negative. That does not work. As soon as I wrap the listview databind in the !IsPostBack there's an error. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: When a user adds an item to this ListBox, do you want the DataBase to update or should it simply hold the data. If you want the data held, you should create a variable in your page, such as a `List<ListItem>` that you repopulate the ListView with every time.

Comment: In that case, once the event fires, at the beginning, you should insert the new data into the database, then DataBind it once the Insert completes. Then you will pull the data back out properly.

Comment: no still not it. 
I got close by using the itemcommand behavior for the listview. but I can't access the insert template textbox to put the value.